# See what git branches (or tags) point to given commit hash?

Tags: git

I can achieve the effect I want by running:

```
git log -1 --decorate --oneline <commit hash>
```

and reading the tag names and branch names.

Is there a way to get this information directly?

Essentially what I want is the inverse operation of:

```
git rev-parse <tag or branch>^{commit}
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that is a very different question, not a duplicate.  The answers there are all information I was aware of when I wrote this question.

Comment: I realized that after looking a little more closely. I rescinded my close vote but didn't delete the automatically generated comment. My apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git 2.7.0 introduced a `--points-at` flag to various subcommands:

```
git for-each-ref --points-at <commit> --format '%(refname)'
git branch --points-at <commit>
git tag --points-at <commit>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in git 2.5.3.  (When was `--points-at` introduced?)  Any other way that will work in older versions?

Comment: I don't know. Does `git branch --points-at <commit>` (same for `tag`) work?

Comment: Apparently the flag was introduced on 2.7.0 (looking at the man page).

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch --contains <commit>
git tag --contains <commit>
```

**Edit**: To find the refs that point exactly to hash `abc123`, do:

```
git show-ref | awk '/^abc123/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted; I only want to know of any tags or branches that point to *exactly* the commit hash I'm specifying.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. MForster's answer is what you need then.

Comment: @Wildcard, I added a way to do it with `awk` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have git 2.7+ you can still use `git for-each-ref` to find refs that point at specific commits, by filtering the `for-each-ref` output:

```
git for-each-ref | grep ^1234567
```

for instance.  [Edit: this is essentially the same as [using `git show-ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444965/1256452), except that following tags to their target requires more typing.  The for-each-ref output is meant for scripts, though, so if you want to write a script, it's probably better to use this than to use `git show-ref`.]