# List all Git branches currently at specified commit

Tags: git

Is there a Git command (or series of commands) which, given a commit SHA, lists all branches *currently* at that commit?

For example, given the following state:

```
* 040cc7c     (HEAD, master)
| 
| * a9a246b   (develop, feature_a)
| * 73b91cc   
| * 001b20a   (feature_b, feature_c)
|/
* d642f88
```

Issuing the hypothetical command `git <something> 001b20a` would output `feature_b`, `feature_c`. Note that I don't want to see `develop` or `feature_a` in the output; therefore I don't think `git branch --contains 001b20a` is the correct command, at least not in its vanilla form.

Comment: As a sidenote, `git log -1 <commit hash OR branch name> --pretty=format:"%d"` will list branches but also tags (**not required here**) pointing at said commit (by showing decorations).

Comment: I think this is a great example of posting a question and answer together when you research something and find the answer, and want to help the community. This is a well written question and nice answer. Unfortunately in this particular case though, it is a dup: [See what git branches (or tags) point to given commit hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444831/see-what-git-branches-or-tags-point-to-given-commit-hash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to achieve this behaviour is:

```
git branch --points-at <commit SHA>
```

This can be modified using the `--remotes` flag to only show remote branches, or `--all` to show both remote and local-tracking branches.