# How can I display the version number in git for the hash value of a tag?

Tags: git, powershell, tags, git-tag

I am working on the PowerShell right now and would like to display the version and if possible the description of a tag from which I get the hash value. By version I mean something like 55.1.

How can I do this on the PowerShell?

I thank you already for help

Comment: Maybe just `git tag --points-at=<your_hash>`

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- define an [alias for git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934012/6309)
- or [install Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), which will with tab completion support for common git commands.

In both cases, you will be able to type:

```
git show-ref --tags
```

To [list tags version and their sha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796647/6309)

Or, for a given commit SHA:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --tags --no-walk -1 <SHA>
```

Or, as suggested, [with git 2.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444988/6309):

```
git for-each-ref --points-at <commit> --format '%(refname)'
git branch --points-at <commit>
git tag --points-at <commit>
```